# Used to work-- Automated screenshots in Safari using AppleScript

Tags: applescript, screenshot, screen-capture

My AppleScript used to work to take multiple screenshots of a specified area in Safari.  Now I get an error message: Safari got an error.  No file specified.

What is wrong?

I open Safari in the full screen mode, then it automatically takes a new screenshot of this area every second. I would greatly appreciate some help!

```
repeat

    tell application "Safari"

        do shell script "date=$(date '+%Y%m%dT%H%M%S'); screencapture -x -R210,347,700,610~/Desktop/screen_${date}.png"

        say "Click!"

    end tell

    delay 1

end repeat
```

Answer (score 0):

In a shell script line parameters are separated by spaces so between the screen dimensions and the file path there must be a space character.

And `do shell script` and `say` don't belong to Safari.

```
repeat
    do shell script "date=$(date '+%Y%m%dT%H%M%S'); screencapture -x -R210,347,700,610 ~/Desktop/screen_${date}.png"
    say "Click!
    delay 1
end repeat
```